# Codeigniter: from sql to activerecord, what is the wrong?

Tags: sql, codeigniter, activerecord

I want to try change my sql code to active record, here is the original code and active record try. And the error message. Please tell me where is my wrong? Thanks.

```
SELECT `emlakilan`.`id`, `emlakdurum`.`durum`,`emlaktip`.`tip`,`semtler`.`semt`,`emlakilan`.`fiyat`,`emlakilan`.`tarih`,`resim`.`r1` FROM ucburcak.`emlakilan`
INNER JOIN `semtler` ON `emlakilan`.`semtId` = `semtler`.`semtid`
INNER JOIN `emlaktip` ON `emlakilan`.`emlakTipId` = `emlaktip`.`id`
INNER JOIN `emlakdurum` ON `emlakilan`.`emlakDurumId` =`emlakdurum`.`id`
LEFT JOIN `resim` ON `emlakilan`.`resimId` = `resim`.`id`
WHERE `emlakdurumId`=3 ORDER BY `emlakilan`.`id` DESC LIMIT 4;
```

//and here active record function

```
public function kucuk_ilan($durum ='3') // $durum:1=>tümü 2=>kiralık 3=>satılık 4=>takas
    {
            $query = $this->db->select('emlakilan.id, emlakdurum.durum, emlaktip.tip, semtler.semt, emlakilan.fiyat, emlakilan.tarih, resim.r1')
                              ->from('emlakilan')
                              ->join('semtler','emlakilan.semtId' === 'semtler.semtid','inner')
                              ->join('emlaktip','emlakilan.emlakTipId'==='emlaktip.id','inner')
                              ->join('emlakdurum','emlakilan.emlakDurumId'==='emlakdurum.id','inner')
                              ->join('resim','emlakilan.resimId'==='resim.id','left')
                              ->where('emlakdurumId'===$durum)
                              ->order_by('emlakilan.id','desc')
                              ->limit(4);
            $query = $this->db->get('emlakilan');

            return $query->result_array();
    }
```

And, error message:

Error Number: 1066

Not unique table/alias: 'emlakilan'

SELECT `emlakilan`.`id`, `emlakdurum`.`durum`, `emlaktip`.`tip`, `semtler`.`semt`, `emlakilan`.`fiyat`, `emlakilan`.`tarih`, `resim`.`r1` FROM (`emlakilan`, `emlakilan`) INNER JOIN `semtler` ON INNER JOIN `emlaktip` ON INNER JOIN `emlakdurum` ON LEFT JOIN `resim` ON WHERE `0` IS NULL ORDER BY `emlakilan`.`id` desc LIMIT 4

Filename: C:\Program Files\EasyPHP-12.1\www\3burcak\system\database\DB_driver.php

Line Number: 330

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So 1. remove the 'from' line
2. the joins where wrong

try this:

```
public function kucuk_ilan($durum ='3') // $durum:1=>tümü 2=>kiralık 3=>satılık 4=>takas
{
        $query = $this->db->select('emlakilan.id, emlakdurum.durum, emlaktip.tip, semtler.semt, emlakilan.fiyat, emlakilan.tarih, resim.r1')
                          ->from('emlakilan')
                          ->join('semtler','emlakilan.semtId = semtler.semtid','inner')
                          ->join('emlaktip','emlakilan.emlakTipId = emlaktip.id','inner')
                          ->join('emlakdurum','emlakilan.emlakDurumId = emlakdurum.id','inner')
                          ->join('resim','emlakilan.resimId = resim.id','left')
                          ->where('emlakdurumId', $durum)
                          ->order_by('emlakilan.id','desc')
                          ->limit(4);
        $query = $this->db->get('emlakilan');

        return $query->result_array();
}
```